# How to know total number of users logged in at the moment on Stack Overflow

Tags: support

Is there a way to know at morning/night how many users are logged in?

When there are many users logged in there is more probability to get an answer from there.

Comment: I added some more relevant duplicates. Look at the ones that offer an SEDE query as those give you an accurate indication for what you can expect today.